# python function for retrieving key and encryption

Tags: python

M2Crypto package is not showing the 'recipient_public_key.pem' file at linux terminal.

How do I get/connect with recipient public key.

Exactly, I need to check how can I open this file through linux commands.

```
import M2Crypto
def encrypt():
    recip = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(open('recipient_public_key.pem','rb').read())
    print recip;
    plaintext = whatever i need to encrypt
    msg = recip.public_encrypt(plaintext,RSA.pkcs1_padding)
    print msg;
```

after calling the function its not giving any output and even any error

i also tried as 'Will' said

```
pk = open('public_key.pem','rb').read()
print pk;
rsa = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(pk)
```

what is the mistake I am not getting?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used M2Crypto, but according to the [API documentation](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA-module.html#load_pub_key), `load_pub_key` expects the file name as the argument, not the key itself. Try

```
recip = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key('recipient_public_key.pem')
```